# Does geary have a command flag to compose new email?

Tags: indicator, thunderbird, messaging-menu, geary

I'm trying to update message menu indicator and i want to import some geary funtions as well, does geary have any flags similar to Thunderbird (--compose)?
I tried geary --? but didn't find any relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To launch the composer in Geary, specify a mailto: URI on the command-line:

```
$ geary mailto:user@example.com
```

It's not listed in the --help, unfortunately.  That's ticketed at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722647

Answer (score 2):

In short, it doesn't have, at least for now.

To see list of available commands, you can run

```
geary --help
```

Also I haven't found any useful information on [Geary Website](http://www.yorba.org/projects/geary/) or [Gnome Website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary)

But as Official Website says

> Geary is still in early development.

So there is possibility that this feature will be added in future releases.
If you want to get more information, you should visit [geary-list](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/geary-list)

Answer (score 0):

In XFCE, you can start a compose window in your preferred mail reader with:

```
exo-open mailto:user@example.com
```

[exo-open documentation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-exo-open/#lbAG)

I don't think there's a way to do it without specifying a to address, but you can always change it before sending...